# Add spaces between panels in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and can't seem to figure out how to add padding / space between panels.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4>First Cell</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4>Second Cell</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h4>Third Cell</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a class and setting the width to 30% but it only works if you have two panels and pull the one right. If I add a margin then it throws the responsiveness off and the last cell drops to the next line.

How can I responsively add a gap between the panels?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd be inclined to not combine .panel and .col*:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xTc7a/1/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class=" panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <h4>First Cell</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class=" panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <h4>Second Cell</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class=" panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                 <h4>Third Cell</h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

change the html like below,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-body">
               <h4>First Cell</h4>

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <h4>Second Cell</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <h4>Third Cell</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this and divide to any number of columns as you like.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class=" panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <h4>First Cell</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class=" panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
             <h4>Second Cell</h4>
        </div>
    </div> 
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by adding a class panel-4 to the first 2 panels:

```
.panel-4 {
  width:30%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
```

Comment: Complicating your app with CSS overrides is probably less desirable than a modest restructuring to comply with Bootstrap's intentions. It may make maintenance and upgrades more difficult.